# Installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 on top of Windows Small Business Server 2008

Tags: installation, small-business-server

Has anyone tried to install Foundation on top of SBS 2008. The installation should be typical as for any other Windows 2008 Server but the problem is there are so much components there like Exchange etc. and I wonder if there is anything special we should look at.

On typical Windows 2008 Server installation PowerShell v1 needs to be removed but is that going to impact Exchange that is installed on the same box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitepaper has been released that explains this upgrade process:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff959273(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but I think the current builds are very finicky with the pre-requisites.  If this is a live server I wouldn't attempt it.

PowerShell v1 does need to be removed, but the v1 scripts should still run fine in the v2 CTP version.

Answer (score 0):

As this is still a Beta product, do not install on your Live Production box.  You can consider trying this on a seperate Test environment or wait till 12th May, when final release of SP 2010 will be available.

In any case, its a good practice to try on seperate server, before doing on any Production servers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [post on the SharePoint Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2010/01/22/operating-system-requirements-of-sharepoint-2010.aspx) stating that this is supported which refers to the [official requirements page on TechNet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements) - but this doesn't mention it at all!

The best reference at this stage is [this thread on TechNet Forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3307da4e-2f31-4165-8794-dc156248754e/upgrading-to-sharepoint-2010-foundation-on-sbs-server-2008?forum=sharepointadminprevious). To summarise, there is a whitepaper coming at some point about it but there are some major issues. For example, [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119200552/http://supportweb.ciaops.net.au/blog/archive/2010/04/26/sharepoint-foundation-2010-on-sbs-2008.aspx) shows that SPF 2010 can't be installed on a domain controller.